# Weblogic server log fills up with <BEA-010213>

Tags: weblogic

My Weblogic server log fills up with this error message:

```
####<Mar 2, 2015 11:38:57 AM MST> <Info> <EJB> <max75demo> <MAXIMOSERVER> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1425321537312> <BEA-010213> <Message-Driven EJB: JMSContQueueProcessor-1's transaction was rolled back. The transaction details are: Xid=BEA1-73C4DAA3AC1F8569980C(21198065),Status=Rolled back. [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.AppSetRollbackOnlyException: setRollbackOnly called on transaction],numRepliesOwedMe=0,numRepliesOwedOthers=0,seconds since begin=0,seconds left=60,XAServerResourceInfo[WLStore_mydomain_cqinstore]=(ServerResourceInfo[WLStore_mydomain_cqinstore]=(state=rolledback,assigned=MAXIMOSERVER),xar=WLStore_mydomain_cqinstore21478888,re-Registered
= false),SCInfo[mydomain+MAXIMOSERVER]=(state=rolledback),OwnerTransactionManager=ServerTM[ServerCoordinatorDescriptor=(CoordinatorURL=MAXIMOSERVER+10.0.0.11:80+mydomain+t3+, XAResources={WLStore_mydomain_sqinstore, WLStore_mydomain_sqoutstore, WSATGatewayRM_MAXIMOSERVER_mydomain, WLStore_mydomain_cqinstore},NonXAResources={})],CoordinatorURL=MAXIMOSERVER+10.0.0.11:80+mydomain+t3+).>
```

These logs consume disk space at 5MB/s, causing my small drive to fill up quickly.  The only recent change out of the ordinary was that I synced the machine's time with a time server and changed the time zone.  I have since cleared out the tmp folder and have restarted the server but to no avail.  I'm running Weblogic 10.3.3.0.

Is there something I can do to prevent these errors from occurring?

Thanks!

Comment: It could be related to your time change and a sync issue - admin server not agreeing on the same time as a managed server or some such. That said, have you set `Limit number of retained files` on the `Server->Logging` page in the admin console? Then it at least won't fill up your disk

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip.

In my case, a co-worker had made some changes to an enterprise product on the host I was using (without informing me) which was likely causing these error messages, since the change involved JMS queues.  Had nothing to do with the time change.